# Finding the best environment to test different PHP versions

Tags: php, wamp, version, lamp

I've got Apache + PHP 5.2.17 + mySQL on a Linux/Ubuntu server, and I was requested to upgrade the PHP version (I guess to 5.3.x or 5.4.x).

I would like to test my code in a versatile environment where I can switch among the PHP versions, and I'm trying to locate the proper software. I'm not sure whether 'UwAmp' or 'Laragon' could fit my needs (I don't mind to test it on a Windows machine).

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: do you need any apache functionality (e.g. htaccess)? if not, you could just use the build in php server. another option would be using docker

Comment: by the way... why the update to 5.3 or 5.4? they aren't supported for years

Comment: Why do you need to test many different versions? I would just determine which version I needed to upgrade to and make it work in that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've got Apache + PHP 5.2.17 + mySQL on a Linux/Ubuntu server, and I was requested to upgrade the PHP version (I guess to 5.3.x or 5.4.x).

Do yourself a favour and update to a version of php that have not been abandoned for *years*, at least 7.1. For reference, find the supported versions [here](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). PHP 5.6 is not even in security fixes support anymore.

> I would like to test my code in a versatile environment where I can switch among the PHP versions, and I'm trying to locate the proper software.

Use a local development server stack such as [Ampps](https://www.ampps.com/), MAMP, XAMP, or one of the myriad of such software. They allow for easy switching between php versions.

Alternatively, set up [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/) with different php versions and a suite of tests. Travis is geared up to run tests suites in various PHP versions automagically.

---

Manually compiling and maintaining multiple versions of PHP, while doable, is not very practical if you actually wish to get things done. Using software that comes with multiple versions installed is arguably the only viable solution.